# Solving an infinite order differential equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I got an interesting differential equation:

$(1+D+D^2+D^3+\cdot\cdot\cdot)y = f(y)$

where $D$ is the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $y$ is a function of real variable $x$.

In an attempt to solve this, I took the infinite sum as $\frac{1}{1-D}$.

Then taking it to RHS I could solve the differential equation :
$y=f(y) - \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$

Is this a correct method of solving this problem? please suggest a proper method to solve this.

**EDIT :**

My rationale behind using the formula was:

let $f$ be a trial function such that
$$(1+D+D^2+\cdot\cdot)f=g$$
$$f+D( (1+D+D^2+\cdot\cdot)f) = g$$
$$f+D(g) = g$$
$$f=(1-D)g$$
$$\frac{1}{1-D}f = g$$

**UPDATE**

An $n^{th}$ order ODE should have $n$ arbitrary constants. Here after simplification it has only 1. I think that is useful.

Comment: D is an operator, I doubt you can simply use the result for an infinite geometric series like this.

Comment: How do you prove that your operator series converges and how do you define convergence? It's also a good idea to specify what function space does $y$ belong to

Comment: Left-multiplying by $1-D$ gives $y=f(y)-y^\prime f^\prime(y)$, but a solution $y_0$ of this equation doesn't necessarily satisfy $f(y_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^nD^ky_0$, with the RHS a pointwise limit of a sequence of functions. (This is @Yutiy's point.)

Comment: @Prometheus Actually, we can. Check the book on Differential Equations by George Simmons - there is a section devoted to the algebra of differential operators.

Comment: If you are a mathematician, you should be worried about weather the sum on the left converges to anything at all. Which function space are you considering? What kind of convergence? (there is strong, weak, norm, and many other kinds of topologies on the space of operators). If you a are a physicist however, your symbolic non-rigorous reasoning will probably be acceptable if it provides a useful result for your concrete problem.

Comment: I'm a physicist :D and @Simon you are right... we don't count spaces. Its not that I won't count... I don't know!!. The symbolic non-rigorous reasoning for convergence is that : in the specific case I'm trying to solve, y(x) represents a logistically growing population and hence, It does converge in real life. Also I have numerically solved this upto 4th order and the results converged. But I can't say the operator series converges or not. Sorry for being not precise. You may assume the rest of the properties you want... I'll adjust :D

Comment: @Burarian : Unfortunately no. There no reason for convergence of the operator series or correctness of the result is given. Also, if my **UPDATE** is correct, the series : $1+D+D^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot$ cannot be written as $\frac{1}{1-D}$

Comment: What exactly is the operator $\frac{1}{1-D}$ ? Answer that question first.

Comment: @K.defaoite : from the derivation, it is clear that $\frac{1}{1-D}$ is an inverse operation. To find $y$, we solve the differential equation : $(1-D)f(y) = y$ where $D = \frac{d}{dx}$